# better PHP variable equals itself

Tags: php, variables

In PHP, is there a better way to say a variable equals itself, example:

```
$floor = floor($difference / $key);
if($floor > 1) {
    $value .= "s";
} else {
    $value .= "";
};
```

On the fourth line, we're saying `$floor` equals itself plus an empty string. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why on earth does that line exist in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure what you asked. Couldn't you just skip the `else` entirely?

Comment: OMG! Sorry, it's late, my silly, really big mistake! I'm going to update my question now, i got my variable names wrong. Note, the variable $value will not have been initialised!

Comment: Your question still makes no sense.  If `$value` has not been initialized, why are you concating to it?  What do you expect it to hold after the `else`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

You can do nothing.
`$floor` already equals itself.  You can remove the entire `else` block.

Comment: Sorry, if $floor was not already initialised then I'd get an error if I called the variable $floor later in the code, and $floor had not been greater than 1. I am askig if there is a better way to say "$floor = $floor". Thank you for your rapid reply!

Comment: @Jonathon: What are you talking about? If it's not initialized yet, you'll get the same error here.

Comment: My stupid mistake, please reread my edited question! Extremely sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Your updated code still doesn't make sense. You're not assigning, you're concatenating. Is this what you meant to do?

```
if($floor > 1) {
    $value = "s";
} else {
    $value = "";
}
```

You can shorten this using the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
$value = ($floor > 1) ? 's' : '';
```

If `$value` is already an empty string, you don't need to take any action. Not every `if` statement has to have a matching `else`.